# Most visited Page in Google Analytics - Malware?

Tags: google-analytics

I have website being monitored by Google Analytics. One of the most visited pages is

```
/?from=http://www.traffic2cash.xyz/
```

What does it mean? Somebody tried to inject some malware (...) into the website or something similar? It happened maybe only during 3 days in month so it should be not big deal, but I still better ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what's called *ghost referral spam*. They didn't actually visit your website but rather they used Google Analytics' Measurement Protocol API to send hits to your UA property. There's nothing you can do about this and it's a known issue with Google Analytics.

Comment: Thanks. So that is nothing to be worried about, no security breach etc. It just messes up with the statistics. Correct?

Comment: Correct. It's literally just spam that's injected into the API by guessing a UA code. It's a huge pain but it's not a security threat.

Comment: Perfect. Already found a way how to deal with it. Thanks once again. For reference: http://www.ohow.co/what-is-referrer-spam-how-stop-it-guide/ .